# How can I write drop courses method using java?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I have already written adding method by the user input, see the code here.

```
@Override
public void adding(int quantity) {


    LinkedList<String> course = new LinkedList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many coursess do you want to add: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print("Insert Course: ");
        String element = input.next();
        course.add(element);
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Course added successfully\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(course.get(i));
    }

}
```

Now I need to drop courses from my adding method by user input. How can i do this?

```
  @Override
public void dropping(int quantity) {

}
```

Comment: What do you want your method to do? Drop some number of courses (`quantity`)?

Comment: no, i need to drop the course . but quantity will be returned  from dropping method.

Comment: @AlaminSheikh - Why is this a problem for you? It will be similar to your `adding(int quantity)` method except the line, `course.add(element);` which you need to replace with `course.remove(element);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please code inline comments for code explanation and there can be lot of improvement to the code like,

- `int quantity` is never used
- `course` is initialized but how are you going to share it with `adding` + `dropping` method

```
public static int dropping(int quantity) {    
        LinkedList<String> course = new LinkedList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many courses do you want to drop: ");
        int num = input.nextInt();   // accepting the total no. of subject to delete from user
        quantity = num;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print("Delete Course: ");
            String element = input.next(); // accept the subject name from user
            course.remove(element);    // remove from the subject from the list
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Course deleted successfully\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(course.get(i));
        }
        return quantity;  // retrurn the no. of subject deletes attempted by user
    }
```

Comment: but I can't return quantity?

Comment: what value your `quantity` will have ? Is the no. of subject to be deleted? you question says the method return type is `void` you need to change the signature as well

Comment: feel free to upvote + accept it if it has solved your problem @AlaminSheikh

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in the arraylist and the use remove()